# Configure spring-social to work via proxy

Tags: java, spring, proxy, spring-social

I tried to run app with spring-social module. But when connection to twitter should be established i got an exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I know that is because of proxy, if it run on another computer without proxy its works fine. Method of declaring proxy parameters like:

```
System.setProperty( "http.proxyPort", "8090" );
System.setProperty( "https.proxyPort", "8090" );
System.setProperty( "http.proxyHost", "192.168.1.50" );
System.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "192.168.1.50" );
```

or pass VM arguments at start:

```
-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.1.50 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8090 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.1.50 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8090
```

don't work. It helps only when I use spring-social+spring-boot. As far as I understand spring-boot has something for initializing inner `RestTemplate` (in `Twitter.class`) with proxy settings.

Actually the question: how initialize spring-social to use proxy, if spring boot doesn't used in application? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very stupid mistake cost many hours. May be it would be helpful for somebody. To configure spring-social needed configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig
    extends SocialConfigurerAdapter
{
...
}
```

there are number of methods, one of which is

```
@Override
public void addConnectionFactories( ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig)
{
    TwitterConnectionFactory twitterConnectionFactory = new TwitterConnectionFactory( "twitter.appId", "twitter.appSecret" );
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory( twitterConnectionFactory );
}
```

in this method creates TwitterConnectionFactory... and it contains `RestTemplate`, which sends request to twitter. So setting of `System` proxy properties should be before factory creation. so the simplest case is:

```
@Override
public void addConnectionFactories( ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig )
{    
    System.setProperty( "http.proxyPort", "8090" );
    System.setProperty( "https.proxyPort", "8090" );
    System.setProperty( "http.proxyHost", "192.168.1.50" );
    System.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "192.168.1.50" );
    TwitterConnectionFactory twitterConnectionFactory = new TwitterConnectionFactory( "twitter.appId", "twitter.appSecret" );
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory( twitterConnectionFactory );
}
```

Unfortunately, I set this properties a bit later :(